# Missing files from docker container created from an image through 'docker save'

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

A colleague is moving away and he's been trying to send me his work through docker images.
We tried 'docker commit', 'docker save' and then on my side 'docker load' and files that would normally be there (ie, /blah_folder/blah_file.txt) do not show up, only the 'blah_folder'.

Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: You should check a `Dockerfile` into source control and use that to build image reproducibly.  You shouldn't usually need `docker save` and `docker load` unless you're in an environment where it's impossible to use a networked Docker registry, and you shouldn't need `docker commit` ever.

Comment: Well then, how do we get a dockerfile from our docker image?
and I don't have access to the internet on that computer, which is why we are doing it this way to send each other these files over usb.